# Списки в С++. Определить максимальный элемент списка

Tags: c++, списки

Прошу помощи, необходимо найти максимальный элемент списка. Вот есть пример то что я сделал, дальше что-то не соображу.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

struct item_list
{
string data;
item_list* next; 
};


void add_begin (item_list* &h, string s)
    {
        item_list* t=new item_list;
        t->data=s;
        t->next=h;
        h=t;
    }

void add_end (item_list* h, string s)

    {
        item_list* t=new item_list;
        t->data=s;
        t->next=0;
        item_list* a=h;
        while(a->next!=0)
        a=a->next;
        a->next=t;
    }

void print(item_list* h)
{
  item_list* t=h;
  while(t!=0)
    {
    cout<<t->data<<" ";
    t=t->next;
    }
  cout<<endl;
}


int main()
{

    item_list* l=0;
    add_begin(l,"1");
    add_begin(l,"2");
    add_end(l,"1");
    add_end(l,"4"); 
    add_begin(l,"0");
    print (l);  


return 0;
}
```

Comment: плохой подход создать список

Comment: А что произойдет, если я для нового списка сразу сделаю `add_end`?

Comment: это добавление элемента в конец списка, разницы нету где ты его расположишь

Answer (score 3):

Зачем городить свой велосипед, если можно просто использовать [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)?

```
std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, -14, 1, 5, 9 }; 
auto result = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: просто потому что ему так хочется. Человек экспериминтирует

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ок. я ответил на вопрос в заголовке. остальное - из разряда "у меня не работает - сделайте за меня"

Comment: @ Andrey Semenov, тут нечего делать, у него просто есть адрес обьекта, который содержит строку, которая просто построилась в результате многократного присваивания. И что в строке с чем сравнивать  не понятно, но  я так понел, что автору просто интересно вот так поэспериментировать

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о том, что вас интересует как именно после вашего кода можно будет найти максимальный элемент, то самый легкий путь загрузить их в контейнер. В вашем случаи эффективнее сортировать вставками, толкая их в очередь с приоритетом, где головной элемент будет ваш  max, к тому же, при желании вы можете поменять компаратор...

```
//...
#include <queue>
// ваш класс
int main()
{   
    item_list* l = 0;
    add_begin(l,"1");
    add_begin(l,"2");
    add_end(l,"1");
    add_end(l,"4");
    add_begin(l,"0");

    std::priority_queue<std::string> heap;
    item_list* p = l;     // чтоб не терять ваш обьект
    while (p) {
     heap.push(p->data);
     p = p->next;
    }
    std::cout << heap.top(); // печатаем головной элемент, т. е. max_element
    // или храним его где то
    std::string smax = heap.top();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно и более лучше написать, но думаю, если вы захотите, то и сами напишете :)

```
item_list* find_max(item_list *list)
{
    item_list *head = list;
    item_list *max = list;
    while (head)
    {
        int num = atoi(head->data.c_str());
        if (num > atoi(max->data.c_str())) max = head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return max;
}
```